# vscode - Display find flag (Match case/Whole word/Regex) in the status bar

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, find, status

Is there a way to get the active find flag (Match case/Whole word/Regex) in the status bar?
Sometimes I use Shift+L to edit at several places but I get the wrong matches because I forget which one is the active find flag.

Any directions about settings or extensions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are referring to this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106570 (Highlight similar text depends on search settings)

It looks like the solution, it is in the Insiders' Build now, is to display the find options bar (with Match Case, etc.) briefly in the upper right corner when you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or double-click on a word AND the find widget is not visible.

It is brief, like it is shown for 2 seconds, but at least it will remind you of the current selected options.  You may want to chime in on the issue to register whether you like the "solution".